# Validating user input with a loop

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Alrighty, I'm currently trying to make a program that takes input, in the form of a email address, from the user and checks to see if it has a '@' in it. I want to use a loop to steps through the whole string that the user entered, and checks each character for the '@'. I'm a little lost as to how to get started.

What I did, was use a for loop to iterate through the whole string that the user entered. Then I used a do/while loop to execute a certain line of code until the user entered a valid email. However, it seems to always be valid no matter if it has a '@' or not. I also want to check if it only contains 1 '@' in it. I'm a little lost as you can see, but any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.print("Enter an email address ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        valid c = new valid(input);
    }
}

class valid
{
    String scan2;
    char amper = '@';
    int i;
    valid(String scan1)
    {
        scan2 = scan1;

        for (i = scan2.length() - 1 ; i <= 0; i--)
            do
            {
                System.out.print("That input is invalid");

            }   while(scan2.indexOf(i) != amper);

        System.out.println("That input is valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Just use `string.contains("@")`

Comment: I know, but it's part of an assignment. We are learning about getting familiar with running through a string with a loop

Comment: Do you understand what [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) returns?

Comment: Remove your do/while loop and check `scan2` contains `@` character with a `if` condition inside for loop.

Comment: Use `scan2.charAt(i)`.

Comment: This seems bad design pattern. BTW in Java class name start from big letter.

Comment: You should use a Regex for this.

Comment: Why do you call the '@' character 'amper'? It's not an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to use a loop, I would recommend `charAt`. It gives you the character at a given index in a string:

```
boolean found = false;
//where string is the input that you are scanning to find an email address
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if (string.charAt(i) == '@'){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found){
    System.out.println("Found the @ character!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you

1. Loop the each character in the loop.
2. Check for '@' character

   ```
   String email = "test@gmal.com";
           boolean valid = false;
           for (int i=0;i<=email.length();i++) {
               if (email.charAt(i)== '@') {
                   valid = true;
                   break;
               } 
           }

           if (valid) {
               System.out.println("This is valid email Id");
           } else {
               System.out.println("This is an Invalid email Id");
           }
   ```

Comment: `if (inValid) {System.out.println("Valid");}` seems confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

Others have already made some helpful comments, but here a few other things I have noticed:

- Did you mean to have no "{} after the for statement?  Not having that { } can change the program.
- In the for statement, did you want it to be i <= 0 or i >= 0?  If i starts out being the length of the input string and the test in the for statement is i <= 0, it will never be true unless the input is zero length.
- Why do you have a scan1 and a scan2 String?
- You may want to consider removing your search logic from the constructor.

Comment: Since he's using `i = scan2.length() - 1`, an input of a single character or an empty string will result in an infinite loop with `i <= 0`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, thanks.  There is in infinite loop in there.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc concerning indexOf:

> the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.

For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your E-Mail:");

String line;
do {
   line = sc.nextLine();
}
while(line.indexOf('@') == -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using charAt() method in this case. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmailAddr {
    private String emailAddress;

    public EmailAddr(String emailAddress){
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public boolean isValid(){
        boolean isValid = false;
        int nAtSign = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < emailAddress.length(); i++){
            if(emailAddress.charAt(i) == '@')
                nAtSign++;
        }

        if(nAtSign == 1)
            isValid = true;
        return isValid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your email address: ");
        EmailAddr emailTest = new EmailAddr(sc.nextLine());
        sc.close();

        if(emailTest.isValid()){
            System.out.println("The email address is VALID!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The email address is INVALID!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Why dont you try with regular expressions ??

```
public class EmailValidation {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag;
do{
    String pattern="[a-zA-Z]*@[a-zA-Z.]*";

    //if u need to think of much better email validation..
    //String pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$";

    System.out.println("Enter your Email  here :");
    flag=scanner.next().matches(pattern);
    if(!flag){
        System.out.println("Not a valid Email.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Valid Email.");
    }

}while(!flag); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as `class valid`.

```
class valid {

    String scan2;
    char amper = '@';
    boolean isFound = false;

    valid(String scan1) {
       scan2 = scan1;

       for (int i = 0; i < scan2.length(); i++) {
            if (scan2.charAt(i) == amper) {
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(isFound) {
            System.out.println("Seems like valid email.");
        }
    }
}
```

This code based on your `class valid` and continue some critical errors. As example : "*What happen if user input contains more `@` characters.*